# NoClassDefFoundError for kafka in tests

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker` error in my integration tests after updating my SpringBoot version from 2.3.4.RELEASE to 2.7.14. My current build.gradle for kafka are as follows:

```
// Kafka
implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '3.4.1'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '2.9.10'
testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka-test', version: '2.9.10'
testImplementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.13', version: '3.4.1'
testImplementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-metadata', version: '3.4.1'
```

Is this a dependency issue or something else that's causing the error?

Comment: I checked `spring-kafka-test` version `2.9.10` (like in your build.gradle) and that contains `EmbeddedKafkaBroker`, so the test should be able to find the class.

Comment: It can be that your kafka version 3.4.1 is overriding the one that spring import because you add dependency explicitely there. Try removing the line of kafka-clients and try. Spring already import kafka-clients in a different version.

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same error after commenting out that line